# fine_tune faster_resnet101_coco by GTX 1080

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, object-detection, object-detection-api

Is it possible to fine-tuning `faster_rcnn_resnet101_coco` by `GTX 1080` with `object detection api`? Or `faster_rcnn_nasnet`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how much VRAM a 1080 has, but you can train a faster rcnn resnet 101 model on a 1080ti with 11GB RAM. Eyeballing the GPU usage there it should roughly fit 8GB with batch size 1, so I would say yes, you can finetune a RCNN resnet101 object detector using the object detection api.

Comment: Thanks for your attention, but i want to answer someone really done with 1080.
Because I do anything it don't answer. Let's see if anyone really done this with 1080?